# How to apply Direct function in Stream.map() like in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, functional-programming, java-stream

Have a question, when I use a stream map in Java I have to be explicit with the lambda. Suppose I have this mapper function:

```
public static Integer mapFunction(Integer number){
    return number + 3;
}
```

And then I want to apply it to a certain List, I have to do this:

```
myList.stream().map(element -> mapFunction(element))
```

So my question is if I can do something similar to what can be done in JavaScript, like

```
myList.map(mapFunction)
```

Like pass the function directly to it without having explicitly tell it to do it for each element.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, `myList.map(mapFunction)` will work just fine

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `Function<Integer, Integer> mapFunction = x -> x+3;` and then using that like this (just as a demo): `List<Integer> newList = myList.stream().map(mapFunction).toList();`?

Comment: Kind of, but mapFunction throws me an error

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: I think for context, Java says that cannot resolve mapFunction, it can be solved using the answer below, like `myList.stream().map(this::mapFunction)`. `mapFunction` needs to be defined in the same class.

Comment: The point of using `Function<Integer, Integer> mapFunction` is that you now have a variable (representing a function) that you can pass between classes. It does not need to be defined in the same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Stream.map()` in Java is not an equivalent of `Array.map()` in JavaScript, which immediately produces another array (dynamic array).

#### Streams

Firstly, there's a notion of **Stream** which is a sequence of elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate operations. It's not a container of data, but the mean of iteration.

A *Stream* has a *source*, can potentially have some *intermediate operations* (they are optional), and a single *terminal operation*, which triggers the execution of the stream.

A stream-source can be a collection or an array, a string, or a generator function like `Random.ints()`. During stream execution, elements are being lazily from the source one by one and each operation in the stream pipeline would be applied on a particular element only if it's needed.

[`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) - is an *intermediate operation*, i.e. produces another stream - `Stream<R>`. It's mean to transform the elements of the stream and expects a function that does this transformation, but doesn't produce the result.

In order to obtain the result, we need to apply a *terminal operation*, i.e. an operation that consumes a stream and produces a value. To generate  a list from the result, we have two options: apply `collect()` by passing a built-in *collector* `toList()` as an argument, or make use of Java 16 method `toList()` which produces an immutable list.

#### Java Functions

As well as *methods* in Java are not completely as functions in JavaScript where they [*first class citizens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) (Java methods are not), *Java 8 functions* are not the same as methods.

Java 8 functions can be expressed either as [**Lambda expressions**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) or [**Method references**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

In short, there's no same kind of *functional type*, instead we have a notion of a **Functional interface**, which is an interface that has only one abstract method. And both *lambda expressions* and *method references* should conform to a *functional interface*, i.e. they provide implementation to a particular *functional interface*.

So there are two ways in which you can create your `Function`.

As a lambda:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> func = i -> mapFunction(i);
```

Or as a *method reference* (since you have this functionality already implemented as a method).

If method `mapFunction()` is `static`:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> func = ClassName::mapFunction; //
```

Where `ClassName` is the name of a class in which `mapFunction()` method resides.

In case if `mapFunction()` is an *instance method*:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> func = objectName::mapFunction;
```

Where `objectName` is the name of an instance of a class in which `mapFunction()` method resides.

And the overall stream pipeline would look like that:

```java
List<Integer> result = numbers.stream()
    .map(ClassName::mapFunction)     // or `objectName::mapFunction` if `mapFunction()` is an instance method
    .collect(Collectors.toList());   // or `.toList()` for Java 16+
```

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be exact like the javascript syntax that you wrote but you can use the method reference instead of lambda declaration to tell to iterate over all the element

```
myList.stream().map(MyClass::mapFunction)
```

You have to use `stream()` here as `map()` function is defined in `Stream` class